# Create link directly to specific tab in adminhtml customer edit page?

Tags: magento2.2, tabs

I have created an extension that adds a custom tab in the adminhtml customer interface.  After submitting the form on the page, how can I return the user to my custom tab instead of the default tab on customer edit.

This is the code I use to return to the customer edit page in my controller

```
$redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$redirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
return $redirect;
```

Comment: I am aware of a url piece/param "active_tab", but cannot find an example of how to use it.

Comment: In the orders adminhtml tab construct, I can do this: /sales/order/view/order_id/81248/active_tab/order_creditmemos/key/mybigkeystring/

order_creditmemos comes from name of the corresponding tab element, such as:
<a href="#sales_order_view_tabs_order_creditmemos_content" id="sales_order_view_tabs_order_creditmemos" name="order_creditmemos" title="Order Credit Memos" .... >
However, I have observed that none of the customer tabs have a name property on the link.  Is this an oversite or do the customer tabs not conform or perhaps were not fully redeveloped from Magento 1.9x?

Comment: I'm seeing now that the entire customer tab widget is one big form that gets saved all together, whereas the order tab widget is not fundamentally a giant form.  This probably explains why my plan is not working (even though I am able to submit my own form and take actions and return to the customer edit page, just not the right tab).

Answer (score 0):

@todd `active_tab` works, just need to remember that need to use tab name from xml file

[image]

instead `#` from link

[image]

```
return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath(
    'sales/order/view',
    [
        'order_id' => $orderId,
        'active_tab' => 'sales_order_additional_items',
    ]
);
```